# Jacoco does not update completeness of MockMvc tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, code-coverage, jacoco, mockmvc

I have a Spring Boot application with some RestControllers.

I am testing the RestControllers With MockMvc to reproduce same behaviour as the end user.

The problem is that Jacoco does not update completeness coverage of those tests:

JacocoReport:

*My testes were made to **LegacyController***
[image]

LegacyController has a simple strucuture, like this (I need to modify because my company's policy):

```java
  @GetMapping("/{thing}/{thing2}")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> doSomeThing(@PathVariable("thing") String thing,
                                                     @PathVariable("service") String thing2,
                                                     @RequestBody(required = false) String boody,
                                                     @RequestHeader("Header1") String Header1,
                                                     @RequestHeader("Content-Type") String contentType,
                                                     @RequestParam(value = "OtherThing") String OtherThing,
                                                     @RequestParam(value = "OtherThing2", defaultValue = "defaultValue", required = false) String OtherThing2) {

        return legacyService.crud(thing, thing2, request, Header1, OtherThing, outputType, OtherThing2);
    }
```

And My tests do something like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(LegacyController.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class LegacyControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private LegacyService legacyService;


    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenGetJson_WhenOffsetPageIsPresent_ThenReturnsOk() throws Exception {
        Mockito.doReturn("OK").when(legacyService).request(Mockito.any(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(TokenDTO.class), Mockito.any(HttpHeaders.class));
       

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/gateway/v1/{thing}/{thing2}", "value-thing", "value-thing2")

                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")

                .header("Header1", "Header1 value")
                .queryParam("OtherThing", "OtherThing value")
                .queryParam("OtherThing2", "OtherThing2 Value")
                .content("A BODY GOES HERE"))

                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

    }
    }
```

Here are the pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


 ***HIDDEN DATA****

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

*** MORE HIDDEN DATA ***



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/constant/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/dto/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/enuns/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/exception/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/ApiApplication.class</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-code-coverage-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My tests works fine, do what it was built to do.

The problem is the code coverage does not changing.

Comment: You are sure the contoller is called? Have checked it with a debugger?

Comment: Yep. I debbugged and my controller is called.

Comment: Are the class and package declaration the same in test and main?

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't get it. Did you mean if they are on same structure? Here is how they are: https://imgur.com/a/wSPXktl

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Your Controller returns 201 but you check against 200 in your test? So the test should fail. You should use `MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreate()`

Comment: Yep. This project has some structural issues, and I've just started doing maintenance on it. If you just look at RestController it gets confusing, but legacyService.crud(...) returns a ResponseEntity wtih 200 as status code. Therefore, it overrides the @ResponseStatus annotation in the controller. So just have faith that the tests are working well hehe.

Comment: You are mocking a compete other function `Mockito.doReturn("OK").when(legacyService).request(`?

Comment: The `legacyService.crud(...)` calls the `legacyService.request(...)`. I need to Mock the inner method because `crud(...)` has a validation that need to be tested.

Comment: But that should not tested in a controller unittest. A unit testt should only test one unit

Comment: I agree with you, but there were a few reasons why the test was done this way. Now about the problem, any way to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried in your IDE. Is the coverage shown there?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved by replacing `org.junit.Test` with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

[image]

However, I don't know why it worked.